# MODx Revo Gallery: How to set tags by choosing from list and filter albums by them in resourses

Tags: gallery, modx, modx-revolution

I need to get albums from gallery for 'Closes' which has categoties 'dress, skirts...' and collections (each element from subcategory can relate to different collections) and I need get closes elements filtering by **categories, collections, and other parameters**. But it's difficult to input the same tags in each Gallery item when creating it. How can I make such a catalog with Gallery?

And even more – each gallery item (element) have multiple images of the same item, so now i create *Albums -> Subalbums -> Items*.

I'm not sure can I do this with Gallery extra? May be use MIGx somehow... and code Gallery.

Comment: Im not sure entirely what your after but I would be tempted to create my own PHP snippet that searches the ModX database its self. Eg:

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure entirely what your after but I would be tempted to create my own PHP snippet that searches the ModX database its self. Eg:

```
//TEMP VAR SEARCH
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` WHERE `value` LIKE "%WHAT EVER TAGS YOU HAVE%"';

$tvqresult = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rowstvq = mysql_num_rows($tvqresult);

while ($rowtvq = mysql_fetch_array($tvqresult)) {
$contid =  $rowtvq['contentid'];

//MAIN QUERY
$mainsql = 'SELECT * FROM `modx_site_content` WHERE `id` = ' . $rowtvq['contentid'] . '  AND `template` = 12 AND `published` = 1 AND `deleted` = 0';

$resultmain = mysql_query($mainsql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultmain)) {
  echo "[[Ditto? &parents=`134` &documents=" . $row['id'] . " &tpl=`tempchunk`]]";
}//END MAIN LOOP
}
```

NOTE: This is just normal SQL - with Revo I believe you will had to make some slight adjustments to have it work with PDO.